# URLs in Google Webmaster Tools are shown with "percent-encoding"

Tags: google-search-console, url-encoding

Our site is using Greek characters for some pages. So in *Webmaster Tools -> Crawl -> Crawl Errors*, the URLs are shown in a format like:

`http://www.pandafun.gr/%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%BA%CE%AD%CE%B4%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%B7/%CF%83%CF%80%CE%AF%CF%84%CE%B9/%CE%B2%CE%B9%CE%B2%CE%BB%CE%AF%CE%BF/tag/order:updated/criteria:23`

Other people told me that they see in their computers URLs with Greek characters and not by "percent" encoding.

I tried a lot of setup in different browsers, but didn't have any success.

Is there any way to see them properly in Google Webmaster Tools?

(I am using Win XP, if that matters ...)

Comment: By "see them properly", do you mean see these URLs with Greek characters in your web browser, in Google Webmaster Tools, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see the Webmasters' list with Greek characters and not % coded. Because in order to see the urls that google found an error, I have to click (one at a time) the list entries, then click into the "Server Error" popup window that has a "copy" of the url (again in % coded), and finally wait for the browser to see the "decoded" url.
But if I re-directions in .htaccess include that error, I see the new url and not the initial.
So at the moment I download the list, insert it in an Excel, and then run a macro (in VBA) that translates the % coded urls.

Comment: @AlexKots: Instead of clicking, you could hover over the links (browsers typically show the "readable" version in the status bar).

Comment: Here is the solution for you, these was list of **HTML URL Encoding Reference**. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 3):

Webmaster Tools always shows URLs with percent encoded URLs.     Browsers usually show the URLs to users unencoded in the URL bar for usability.  Behind the scenes, when the browser requests the URL from your server, it sends it percent encoded.

Even in your web browser, it is not always possible to get the "pretty" URL easily.   Despite the fact that Firefox *shows* me the pretty version, when I copy and paste it I get the percent encoded version:

[image: dmoz pretty url]

http://www.dmoz.org/World/Chinese_Traditional/%E5%95%86%E6%A5%AD/%E9%81%8B%E8%BC%B8%E8%88%87%E7%89%A9%E6%B5%81/%E9%85%8D%E9%80%81%E8%88%87%E7%89%A9%E6%B5%81/

The real *canonical* URL for your pages *has* the percent encodings.    Google likes to deal with canonical URLs.   They will always use the percent encoded version internally and in Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 0):

That is the other face of paradigm to separate code from the style. You should understand it like: Unicode is the kind of coding of non-ASCII letterfaces. The browser address line displays its style, like on this image from Stephen Ostermiller
[image]

But the real code of those characters is unicoded way. And the machine-readable way of displaying it will remain the code way. You can try to copypaste your percent-encoded url into the browser address line, enter it - voila, you get the non-encoded, human readable url.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the links paste as many as you like here to see the original characters [Unicode code converter](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/)